# Which dbExpress ServerCharSet do I need for utf8 data in MySQL 5?

Tags: mysql, delphi, utf-8, delphi-2009, dbexpress

We tried `ServerCharSet=utf8` and `ServerCharSet=UTF8`, based on information found in newsgroups - but still, special characters / Umlauts do not appear correctly in the client data.

We use Delphi 2009 and the built-in dbExpress driver. Field data is retrieved using AsWideString.

Answer (score 2):

you have to set up a *client* charset.
Simple "`SET NAMES utf8`" query, executed right after connect, will do the trick