# dbExpress Delphi XE2 and russian letters

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-xe2, dbexpress

I started working with dbExpress and Xe2.
Now i have a trouble with Russian text, i have a "????????????" instead of letters.
[image]
Here is the structure:
In table i have entered by myself russian text. While i Quering , i have something like this:

```
var
  Connection: TSQLConnection;
  Qry: TSQLQuery;
  VersionString: String;
  i:Integer;
begin
  Result:=False;
  Connection := TSQLConnection.Create(nil);
  Connection.DriverName := 'MySQL';
  Connection.GetDriverFunc := 'getSQLDriverMYSQL';
  Connection.LibraryName := 'dbxmys.dll';
  Connection.VendorLib := 'libmysql.dll';
  Connection.LoginPrompt:=False;
  Connection.Params.Values['Database']:=dbName;
  Connection.Params.Values['User_Name']:=dbUser;
  Connection.Params.Values['Password']:=dbPass;
  Connection.Params.Values['HostName']:=dbHost;

  Qry := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  Qry.SQLConnection := Connection;

  Qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM `scan_values` WHERE `city`='''+City+''' AND `type` ='''+Gtype+''';';
  Qry.Open();
  while not Qry.Eof do
  begin
    ComboBoxDestination.Items.Add(Qry.Fields[6].AsString);
    Qry.Next;
  end;
  Result:=true;
  Qry.Close;
  Connection.Free;
end;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the DB, and what character set did you specify in the connection settings?

Comment: MySql , in conn. setting i set nothing... How can i set smth? 
Before using this query's 
SET NAMES ''utf8'' and SET CHARACTER SET ''utf8''  dont help

Comment: Try reading the string with Value or with AsWideString. After you've set the CharSet to utf8

Comment: Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(Qry.Fields[6].AsAnsiString);
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(Qry.Fields[6].AsString);
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(Qry.Fields[6].AsWideString); doesnt help. All time i have same answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598593/which-dbexpress-servercharset-do-i-need-for-utf8-data-in-mysql-5

Answer (score -1):

```
  Connection.Params.Values['CharacterSet']:='utf8';
  Connection.Params.Values['Names']:='utf8';
  Connection.Params.Values['ServerCharSet']:='utf8';
```

It helps me... WHY DEVELOPERS DONT MAKE MANUAL\GUIDES ABOUT THIS??? Only Random helps me...

Comment: Well, I believe that this subject is documented. Perhaps you've not found/read the docs. Also, in what way does this answer address your question?

Comment: But this answer is no good. Which setting does the trick. I think I know.

Comment: This would be documentation related to the database (MySQL), not Delphi, so SHOUT at the developers at MySQL if it's not documented there. The information you've provided here has nothing to do with Delphi; they're all instructions to the underlying database driver. And even if it *did* have something to do with Delphi, it's not users here at StackOverflow you should be complaining to about it; Embarcadero is the one who produces the documentation, so SHOUT at them instead.

Comment: The relevant parameter is ServerCharSet. Parameters set up here configure the dbx driver, as such burden of documentation is indeed on the compiler (driver) vendor. Relevant documentation is [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Setting_Up_TSQLConnection#Specifying_connection_parameters) which mentions very few parameters.